# React-Native error cannot use import outside a module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, facebook, hybrid-mobile-app

[image]com.facebook.react.common.javascriptexception cannot use import outside a module
node v12.13.1
react-native - 0.58.6
react-native-cli- 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export something from your script?

Try add `export { someYourVariable }` to your script

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export